# How to call global function inside class method with same name in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a situation that I need to have global functions and object with same names as global functions.

And similar question: what if I will have a companion object?

Simple example:

file: fooBar.kt

```
fun foo(){} //global foo
fun bar(){} //global bar

class FooBar {

   fun foo(){
       foo() //this makes me a recurrence but I want to call global foo here
   }

   fun bar(){
       bar() //this makes me a recurrence but I want to call global bar here
   }

    companion object {
       fun foo() {
           bar()// how to call global bar here?
       }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Question related to function but solutions is same as in case of variables